# Upgrade Struts Code to latest version 2.5.20 working on Tomcat not at Weblogic12c

Tags: struts2, weblogic12c

**Description:**

I have an application which is implemented in latest version of Struts 2.5.20 with tiles implementation, While deploying WAR file on weblogic12c Server it cause error.

**scenario:**
I have maven project, create WAR file and deploy on tomcat server then all functionality working fine same WAR file I deployed on Weblogic12c server then it cause error.

[image]

I download the whole sample example from below URL: https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/tree/master/tiles

One minor change I made in sample pom.xml that replace **${struts2.version}** with **2.5.20**

**Expected Results:** WAR file need to work on Tomcat and weblogic12c server.

Comment: What is Java version?